# Can't sync photos to the iPad

Tags: sync, ipad

About two months ago I created a folder inside the iPad with a Windows computer named "Wallpaper", and then deleted it.
Now every time I try to sync it keeps telling me this error:

```
Could not sync photos to the iPad: Folder "Wallpaper" could not be found.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to untick "Sync Photos" > Sync your iPad > tick "Sync Photos" > Select "Sync all photos" > Sync your iPad again.